# My slideshow is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I am still fairly new to code, I am working on a new website and I want to implement an automatic slideshow using jquery but it is working wacky.

It allows the pictures to change but after the first successful slide the othe pictures visibly slides below the slideshow.

My html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <link rel="external" type="text/javascript" href="jquery.js"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <div class="slideshow">

        <div>
            <img src="file:///C:/Users/angela/Documents/sandbox/photos/sampleone.png" alt='' width='100%' height='100%'>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="file:///C:/Users/angela/Documents/sandbox/photos/sampletwo.png" alt='' width='100%' height='100%'>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="file:///C:/Users/angela/Documents/sandbox/photos/wood.png" alt='' width='100%' height='100%'>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
.slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

My jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('.slideshow :first-child')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next('img')
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.slideshow');},
    3000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
    function startSlides(start, end, delay) {
      setTimeout(slideshow(start, start, end, delay), delay);
    }

    function slideshow(frame, start, end, delay) {
        return (function() {
          $('#slideshow' + frame).fadeOut();
          if (frame == end) {
            frame = start;
          } else {
            frame += 1;
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#slideshow' + frame).fadeIn();
          }, 850);
          setTimeout(slideshow(frame, start, end, delay), delay + 850);
        })
      }
      // usage: startSlides(first frame, end frame, delay time);
    startSlides(1, 4, 5000);
```

```css
.slide {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: table;
}
.slide div {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3em;
}
#slideshow1 {
  background: #faa;
}
#slideshow2 {
  background: #afa;
}
#slideshow3 {
  background: #aaf;
}
#slideshow4 {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow1" class="slide">
  <div>frame 1</div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow2" class="slide" style="display: none">
  <div>frame 2</div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow3" class="slide" style="display: none">
  <div>frame 3</div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow4" class="slide" style="display: none">
  <div>frame 4</div>
</div>
```

Also, I'd recommend using something along the lines of OwlCarousel, it will make your life easier:
https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel